# Upper and Lower Bounds Proof for Positive Functions

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Is it true that for some function $f:N\to N$, a positive function, then either one of these conditions hold. First is that there is some $a>0$, such that $f(n)\in O(n^a)$. Or Second, there is some $b>1$ such that $f(n)\in\Omega(b^n)$.

So what I understand from this is that $O$ is like the upper bound and $\Omega$ is the lower bound. So now, if we have some positive function say $f(n)=\log(n)$, then one of these conditions always holds? Doesn't the first condition hold for $\log$? Is there a way to prove this for any positive function?

Comment: $\log n$ is not $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh that's true. Then how would I go about proving this?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not true -- a counterexample would be
$$ f(n) = \begin{cases} 1 & n\text{ odd} \\ 2^n & n\text{ even} \end{cases}$$

With a bit more work one can construct strictly increasing examples too, such as this recurrence:
$$ f(0)=1 \qquad f(n+1) = \begin{cases} 2^n & \text{if }f(n)\le 2n \\ f(n)+1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Comment: Umm. Hold on. I meant to ask a slightly different question. Should I ask a new one?

Comment: @user19289: Yes, it's better to ask a new question once the original has been answered. (Unless my recent addition answers what you really meant to ask, of course :-)

Comment: Yes, i'll do that